# What's this regex doing?

Tags: php, regex

I've found this regex in a script I'm customizing. Can someone tell me what its doing?

```
function test( $text) {
    $regex = '/( [\x00-\x7F] | [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF] | [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} | [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3} ) | ./x';
    return preg_replace($regex, '$1', $text);
}
```

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand?  What is the context?

Comment: wooooah !! ,your regex gave me goosebumps :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the capturing group there are four options:

1. `[\x00-\x7F]`
2. `[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]`
3. `[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}`
4. `[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}`

If none of these patterns are matched at a given location, then any character will be matched by the `.` that is outside of the capturing group.

The `preg_replace` call will iterate over `$text` finding all non-overlapping matches, replacing each match with whatever was captured.

There are two possibilities here, either the entire match was inside the capturing group so the replacement doesn't change `$text`, or the `.` at the end matched a single character and that character is removed from `$text`.

Here are some basic examples:

- If a character in the range `\xF8-\xFF` appears in the text, it will always be removed
- A character in `\xC0-\xDF` will be removed unless followed by a character in `\x80-\xBF`
- A character in `\xE0-\xEF` will be removed unless followed by two characters in `\x80-\xBF`
- A character in `\xF0-\xF7` will be removed unless followed by three characters in `\x80-\xBF`
- A character in `\x80-\xBF` will be removed unless it was matched as a part of one of the above cases

Answer (score 2):

The purpose appears to be to "clean" UTF-8 encoded text.  The part in the capturing group,

```
( [\x00-\x7F] | [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF] | [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} | [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3} )
```

...roughly matches a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, which may be one to four bytes long.  The value of the first byte determines how long that particular byte sequence should be.

Since the replacement is simply, `'$1'`, valid byte sequences will be plugged right back into the output.  Any byte that's not matched by that part will instead be matched by the dot (`.`), and effectively removed.

The most important thing to know about this technique is that you should never have to use it.  If you find invalid UTF-8 byte sequences in your UTF-8 encoded text, it means one of two things: it's not really UTF-8, or it's been corrupted.  Instead of "cleaning" it, you should find out how it got dirty and fix *that* problem.

Comment: Although you are correct it's not always possible to clean your input before it reaches PHP. I've just encountered the problem that the code above solves when I use an external tool to process an Excel file which returned as a JSON string.

As the PHP JSON decoder barfs on non UTF characters, they need to be stripped out, which the above code does quite nicely.