# Any Changes to an Ajax script produces an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I am going absolutely crazy here.. I have an ajax.php file that is used to autocomplete a list of names from a table called "contacts". The section of the script is below:

```
dispatch('/ajax/contacts/list', 'ajax_list_contacts');
function ajax_list_contacts() {
    $user = new User(SessionManagement::get_logged_in());
    $gid = $user->get_field('fKeyGroup');

    $q_cons = mysql_query("SELECT '_id', CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS `Name`
                                FROM `contacts`
                                LEFT JOIN `contact_type_options` ON contact_type_options._id = contacts.fKeyContactDetail
                                WHERE (
                                    contacts.fKeyGroup = '{$gid}' AND contact_type_options.type = '2'
                                )")
                                or die(ErrorLog::handle(mysql_error()));

    $out = array();
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_cons)) != null) {
        $out[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($out);
}
```

The above script is called by:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
            success: function(data) {
            var names = [];
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i in data) {
                names.push(data[i].Name);
            }
            $('[name=form-referral]').autocomplete(names);
        },
        url: '/ajax/contacts/list'
    });
```

This works perfectly, and was originally to only call records that had a contact_type_option = 2.  Now, I want to include all contact regardless of the contact type options.

I have tried to change the code entirely to just pull all contacts from the "contacts" table, I have tried removing the part of the script show below. I have tried to change the = '2' to != '3' (as there are only 1-3 different types, and I don't care if type 3 is included) I am mainly interested in types 1 and 2, but I will accept 1,2, and 3 if necessary ... but ANY change I make produces a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null error. It does not make any sense to me why nothing I try is working.

```
AND contact_type_options.type = '2'
```

I have also tried the code below:

```
dispatch('/ajax/contacts/list', 'ajax_list_contacts');
function ajax_list_contacts() {
    $user = new User(SessionManagement::get_logged_in());
    $gid = $user->get_field('fKeyGroup');

    $q_cons = mysql_query("SELECT `_id`, CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) AS `Name`
                                FROM `contacts`
                                WHERE `fKeyGroup` = '{$gid}'")
                                or die(mysql_error());

    $out = array();
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_cons)) != null) {
        $out[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($out);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL from your updated query directly against the database? It'll at least let you know if there's an error in the SQL, or if it's something in the connection that's playing up.

Comment: I tired a direct SQL query and it works fine. I can even change the **type = '2'** to **type != '3'** and it works exactly like I want. But, when I change this in the actual code...it gives the error.

Comment: Then the only other advice I can give is to get your code to output the SQL it's generating, so you can make sure that what it's generating is exactly what you think it's generating.

Comment: I am making headway. It seems that what is killing it is some sort of jquery limit. When I use the **type = '2'**, there are 279 records and it works. When I change it to **type = '1'** there are around 1,485 and it does not work. It now works even if I use **type != '1'** because that is essentially pulling in 279 records. Hmmm

Comment: Is the query timing out, or is it passing back too many records? I'm afraid I don't have enough jquery experience to help with the latter....

Comment: Please can you either accept the answer below or if you've fixed the problem yourself, say what the fix was.

Answer (score 0):

Please try just changing:

```
CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`)
```

to

```
CONCAT("first_name", ' ', "last_name")
```

Obviously that won't return the right data, but it will tell you if there are non-UTF8 characters in your data, which can cause issues with JSON encoding, as JSON only support UTF8 characters.

Obviously making sure your data is correct UTF8 in your database is the best practice, but if you need a quick fix you could just remove the non-UTF8 characters with [What's this regex doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096303/whats-this-regex-doing/7097647)